# LOC and %LOC not working in subroutines on Windows

Tags: windows, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran 90 project which makes extensive use of the loc function to obtain the address of arrays (part of an API for interopability with Matlab).

This code compiles and works on Mac and Linux with both Intel and gfortran, and has for some time (across a couple of different compiler versions).

I am now trying to build on Windows with Intel Fortran from Composer XE 2015. When I step through with the debugger I see that a LOC call in my main function correctly returns the address, but calls within subroutines called from that seem to do nothing - it just returns the value of the data instead of the location.

Does any one have an idea why LOC would not work? I have tried with both loc() and %LOC() and get the same behaviour. For an example see [this function](https://github.com/robince/MatlabAPI_lite/blob/master/tests/test_mx_real_c_double_0.F90). The loc on line 69 works, the one on line 116 doesn't (just returns the value of the data). REPIDX_0(X,1) is a preprocessor macro that in this case just returns X.

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated - I'm completely stuck.

Here is a minimal example:

```
program testloc
  implicit none
  real, pointer :: x
  integer(8) :: add1, add2

  allocate(x)
  x = 2
  add1 = loc(x)
  call get_add(x,add2)
  write(*,*) add1
  write(*,*) add2
  deallocate(x)
contains
  subroutine get_add(x,add)
      real, pointer, intent(in) :: x
      integer(8), intent(out) :: add
      add = loc(x)
  end subroutine
end program
```

On Mac/Linux with ifort 12.1.3 I get the expected output:

```
MatlabAPI_lite robince$ ./a.out
       140661969926608
       140661969926608
```

On Windows with ifort 15.0.1 I get the problematic output:

```
c:\code\MatlabAPI_lite>testloc
         4636400
               2
```

Comment: Show your code, an example should be *in the question itself* (quoted from the reasons to close as off-topic).

Comment: You already use `iso_c_binding` in the code. Why don't you use `type(c_ptr)` and `c_loc()`?

Comment: Well my question is not so much about my code particularly - I have debugged it and have identified the problem is LOC is returning the value and not the address. So my question is how that could happen. I don't remember the details as it was a few years ago now but there was some reason c_ptr and c_loc didn't work for me - don't rememebr if it was lack of compiler support or some other problem. I can revisit that I suppose but I was hoping it would be easier to get the existing code built on windows (since its been stable now for many years on mac and linux)

Comment: If you believe it the error is in the compiler run-time library, you should report it at the proper place = the official vendor's forum, or the official business support site.

Comment: Wait, the variable you call `loc()` on is in fact a pointer. Are you sure Intel describes what it does for pointers the same way you expect it to be? In any case you have to clarify that with them.  Anyway, `target` should be well enough, I don't see any reason for the `pointer` argument there.

Comment: I am not sure if it is an error with the compiler - which is why I was asking here first. It does work without the pointer attribute for the dummy variable in the subroutine. But I need it to work with a pointer because in some of the subroutines I deallocate within the subroutine - target wouldn't allow me to do that. As I say it works on other platforms and with gfortran. I will contact intel but I thought I would ask here first as in the past I have got quick and very useful help on this site - but I have not used the site for some time so perhaps that has changed.

Comment: The variable in the program body is also a pointer, but loc works correctly. The problem seems to be loc on a pointer dummy argument. I cannot find much useful information online but I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70485/discussion-between-robince-and-vladimir-f).

Comment: I got it to work by using c_loc: `#define loc(x) transfer(c_loc(x),0_C_INTPTR_T)`. Thanks for your suggestion. I don't remember why I couldn't get this working when I first developed it - I couldn't get the transfer right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a compiler bug - it is fixed in 15.0.3.